# Как передать токен в методе VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest?

Tags: java, android, api, вконтакте

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(new VKUploadImage(photo, VKImageParameters.jpgImage(0.9f)), 0, 60479154);
```

Как передать тут access_token?

С помощью `VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token)` не работает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это 100% кому-то ещё пригодится:) Решение нашёл сам после 3-х часов поиска. Я сохранял сам **access_token** и **user_id** после авторизации, чтобы сделать возможным управление несколькими аккаунтами и нашёл ключ в хранилище, из которого **VK SD**K берёт значение токена для запросов. И порывшись в самом модуле откопал схему сохранения `VKAccessToken`. Скопировал в основной класс, где мне нужно было это вызывать. Вот что получилось:

```
void SaveTokenInBaseVK() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(VKUIHelper.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putString("VK_SDK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PLEASE_DONT_TOUCH", serialize());
    edit.apply();
}

protected String serialize() {
    return VKStringJoiner.joinParams(tokenParams());
}

public int expiresIn = 0;
public String secret = null;
public boolean httpsRequired = false;
public long created = 0;
public String email = null;
public String access_token = "Тут токен, с которым вы работаете";
public String user_id = "ID пользователя, с которым вы работаете";

protected Map<String, String> tokenParams() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token);
    params.put(EXPIRES_IN, "" + expiresIn);
    params.put(USER_ID, user_id);
    params.put(CREATED, "" + created);
    if (scope != null) {
        params.put(SCOPE, TextUtils.join(",", scope));
    }

    if (secret != null) {
        params.put(SECRET, secret);
    }
    if (httpsRequired) {
        params.put(HTTPS_REQUIRED, "1");
    }
    if (email != null) {
        params.put(EMAIL, email);
    }
    return params;
}
```

Таким образом, я каждый раз в нужном мне месте просто вызываю функцию `SaveTokenInBaseVK()` и спокойно отправляю запрос `VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest()`. При желании, можно после запроса ещё и очищать хранилище.

Comment: Не подскажите как вы в сам запрос VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest добавили токен?